# Algorithm too slow for shuffling ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, shuffle

I am trying to implement the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm on java. It works but when my ArrayList is of a size > 100000, it goes very slow. I will show you my code and do you see any way to optimize the code? I did some research about the complexity of .get and .set from ArrayList and it is O(1) which makes sense to me.

UPDATE 1: I noticed my implementation was wrong. This is the proper Fisher-Yates algorithm. Also I included my `next()` function so you guys can see it. I tested with java.Random to see if my `next()` function was the problem but it gives the same result. I believe the problem is with the usage of my data structure.

UPDATE 2: I made a test and the ArrayList is an instanceof RandomAccess. So the problem is not there.

```
private long next(){ // MurmurHash3

    seed ^= seed >> 33;
    seed *= 0xff51afd7ed558ccdL;
    seed ^= seed >> 33;
    seed *= 0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53L;
    seed ^= seed >> 33;

    return seed;

}


public int next(int range){

    return (int) Math.abs((next() % range));

}

public ArrayList<Integer> shuffle(ArrayList<Integer> pList){

    Integer temp;
    int index;
    int size = pList.size();

    for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--){

        index = next(i + 1);
        temp = pList.get(index);
        pList.set(index, pList.get(i));
        pList.set(i, temp);

    }

    return pList;

}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, next(int size) gives me a random number between 0 to size exclusive.

Comment: So just use "edit" next time ;D and please show us the next() method as it might be the bottleneck as well.

Comment: Show code for next() method...that is probably what is taking so long.

Comment: *crystal ball* : Is there a `Random` instance created in `next`?

Comment: Why are you using a `List` rather than, say `int[]` ?

Comment: You are computing pList.size() everytime the loop iterates, use the size variable instead, other than that as has been said the bottleneck is probably in the next function if the random class is instantiated in that function pull it outside your iterative loop, and pass the instance as a reference variable to next

Comment: Have you tried using LinkedList instead of ArrayList?

Comment: @CocoNess `LinkedList` should be significantly slower in this case, because it does not offer constant-time indexed access.

Comment: This isn't a correct implementation of Fisher-Yates.

Comment: Also note that this is **NOT** the Fisher Yates Shuffle. You are just swapping random elements, and the result of this will not be truly random. (EDIT: I was too slow with this one - it's even an answer already...)

Comment: Isnt it O(n) since it has a for loop in worst case and O(1) in BEST case?

Comment: Also recursion makes anything go down to about O(log) with some other stuff so try recursion instead of the for

Comment: @Paul just update my reply to comment your changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining some fragments that have been scattered in comments and other answers:

- The original code was not an implementation of the [Fisher-Yates-Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). It was only swapping random elements. This means that certain permutations are more likely than others, and the result is not truly random
- If there is a bottleneck, it could (based on the code provided) only be in the `next` method, which you did not say anything about. It should be replaced by the `nextInt` method of an instance of `java.util.Random`

Here is an example of what it may look like. (Note that the `speedTest` method is not even remotely intended as a "benchmark", but should only indicate that the execution time is negligible even for large lists).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

class FisherYatesShuffle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        basicTest();
        speedTest();
    }

    private static void basicTest() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));
        shuffle(list, new Random(0));;
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    private static void speedTest() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int n = 1000000;
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        long before = System.nanoTime();
        shuffle(list, new Random(0));;
        long after = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Duration "+(after-before)/1e6+"ms");
        System.out.println(list.get(0));
    }

    public static <T> void shuffle(List<T> list, Random random) {
        for (int i = list.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
            T t = list.get(index);
            list.set(index, list.get(i));
            list.set(i, t);
        }
    }
}
```

An aside: You gave a list as an argument, and returned the same list. This *may* be appropriate in some cases, but did not make any sense here. There are several options for the signature and behavior of such a method. But most likely, it should receive a `List`, and shuffle this list in-place. In fact, it would also make sense to explicitly check whether the list implements the [java.util.RandomAccess](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) interface. For a `List` that does not implement the `RandomAccess` interface, this algorithm would degrade to quadratic performance. In this case, it would be better to copy the given list into a list that implements `RandomAccess`, shuffle this copy, and the copy the results back into the original list.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Added some comments after you implemented correctly the [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm.

The Fisher-Yates algorithm relies on uniformly distributed random integers to produce unbiased permutations. Using an hash function (MurmurHash3) to generate random numbers and introducing the abs and modulo operations to force the numbers in a fixed range make the implementation less robust.

This implementation uses the [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) PRNG and should work fine for your needs:

```
public <T> List<T> shuffle(List<T> list) {

   // trust the default constructor which sets the seed to a value very likely
   // to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor
   final Random random = new Random();

   final int size = list.size();

   for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      // pick a random number between one and the number
      // of unstruck numbers remaining (inclusive)
      int index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
      list.set(index, list.set(i, list.get(index)));
   }

   return list;

}
```

I can't see any major performance bottleneck in your code. However, here is a fire&forget comparison of the implementation above against the [Collections#shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) method:

```
public void testShuffle() {
   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

   for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
      list.add(i);
   }

   System.out.println("size: " + list.size());

   System.out.println("Fisher-Yates shuffle");
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      shuffle(list);
      long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.out.println("#" + i + " " + (stop - start) + "ms");
   }

   System.out.println("Java shuffle");
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Collections.shuffle(list);
      long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.out.println("#" + i + " " + (stop - start) + "ms");
   }
}
```

which gives me the following results:

```
size: 1000000
Fisher-Yates shuffle
#0 84ms
#1 60ms
#2 42ms
#3 45ms
#4 47ms
#5 46ms
#6 52ms
#7 49ms
#8 47ms
#9 53ms
Java shuffle
#0 60ms
#1 46ms
#2 44ms
#3 48ms
#4 50ms
#5 46ms
#6 46ms
#7 49ms
#8 50ms
#9 47ms
```

Answer (score 1):

(Better suited for Code Review forum.)

I changed what I could:

```
Random random = new Random(42);
for (ListIterator<Integer>.iter = pList.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Integer value = iter.next();
    int index = random.nextInt(size);
    iter.set(pList.get(index));
    pList.set(index, value);
}
```

As an ArrayList is a list of large arrays, you might set the initialCapacity in the ArrayList constructor. `trimToSize()` might do something too. Using a ListIterator means that one already is at the the current partial array, and that might help.

The optional parameter of the Random constructor (here 42) allows to pick a fixed random sequence (= repeatable), allowing during development timing and tracing the same sequence.

Comment: An aside: This is also not the Fisher-Yates-Shuffle. But at least shows the proper use of `java.uti.Random`...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and compare the execution time with your fisher yates method. 
This is probably the "next" method  which is slow

```
function fisherYates(array) {
     for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
     var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
     //swap
     var tmp = array[index];
     array[index] = array[i];
     array[i] = tmp;
}
```